# php foreach break table

Tags: php, foreach, tablerow

Im using tables to store content that's dynamically loaded. It's for a reservation form which will be responsive. What I'm looking to do is break each table row into two if there are more than 5 columns in order for the mobile version to fit on screen.

I'm sure this can be achieved by extending what I already have but can't get it to work.

Here's my current code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($hostel->getAvailableDates() as $date): ?>
        <th><?php echo $date->getDayOfTheWeek(); ?></th>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($hostel->getAvailableDates() as $date): ?>       
        <td>
        <?php if($date->getAvailable()) { ?>            
            <b class="avail tick">Available</b>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <b class="avail cross">Unavailable</b>
        <?php }?>
        </td>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'd need to break the loop for each row `tr` after 5 loops, then add a new row underneath.
I've been experimenting with

```
$max_loop = 5;
$count = 0;
```

But no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to reorganize data:

```
<?php
$availDates = array();
foreach ($hostel->getAvailableDates() as $date) {
    $availDates[] = $date;
}
$maxCols = 5;
$chunked = array_chunk( $availDates, $maxCols );
?>
<table>
    <?php
    foreach ($chunked as $chunk) {
        ?><tr>
        <?php foreach ($chunk as $date): ?>
        <th><?php echo $date->getDayOfTheWeek(); ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($chunk as $date): ?>       
        <td>
        <?php if($date->getAvailable()) { ?>            
            <b class="avail tick">Available</b>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <b class="avail cross">Unavailable</b>
        <?php }?>
        </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr><?php

    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the mod operator. It should give you what you need.

if($count % $max_loop == 0)

Answer (score 0):

If the value returned by getAvailableDates is an array, you could use a for loop instead of a foreach, and check if the current index is a multiple of five, so you don't have to keep track of the count variable

```
$avDates = $hostel->getAvailableDates();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($avDates); $i++)  {
    $date = $avDates[$i];
    //do your staff
    //if multiple of five add another tr
    if ($i % 5 == 0) {

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you. thanks.

```
    <?php

    $avDates = $hostel->getAvailableDates();
    echo "<table><tr>";
    foreach($avDates as $i=>$date){  {
        if ($i == $max_loop) {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
         }
    echo "<td>".($date->getAvailable() ? '<b class="avail tick">Available</b>' : '<b class="avail cross">Unavailable</b>')."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```